# How to move file from one repository to another git repository

Tags: git, github

I have a RepoA and RepoB, I want to move file from RepoA to RepoB. For example

Like this RepoA/Bundle/fileToMove.txt to RepoB/Bundle/fileToMove.txt

But I would like to achieve this with git commands automatically not with manually adding the file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to to checkout both repos, copy the file from `RepoA/Bundle/fileToMove.txt` to `RepoB/Bundle/fileToMove.text` manually, and create a new commit on RepoB where you are adding the file.

Comment: I would like to do automatically through git command not manually.